# Difference of two columns with possible NULL cells

Tags: mysql, select, order-by, query, null

I need to sort a table by the difference of two columns as

```
SELECT (first - second) AS dif
    FROM table1
ORDER BY dif DESC
```

but the two columns can be `NULL`. In this case, it returns the error:

```
BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range
```

The solution to this error is to use `IFNULL(col,0)`, but the problem is that I need `dif` to be `NULL` if any of the columns is `NULL`

Comment: *In this case, it returns the error* **Extremely strange.** I have tested it on MySQL 5.5.60, 5.6.10, 5.6.39, 5.6.40, 5.7.17, 5.7.22, 8.0.11 - all of them give the result you need.

Comment: @Akina you're absolutely right. The problem was not null values, but my unsigned column. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could test for the columns being null before doing the calculation.

```
SELECT if(isnull(first) or isnull(second),null,(ifnull(first,0) - ifnull(secon,0))) AS dif
    FROM table1
ORDER BY dif DESC
```

Answer (score 5):

Many ways of doing this, but I find this readable:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN first IS NULL OR second IS NULL THEN NULL
       ELSE first - second END AS dif
    FROM table1
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If the datatype of the columns is `BIGINT UNSIGNED`, then consider doing `CAST(x AS SIGNED)`

See also the 'operator' `<=>`